# Share Folder Missing File

Tags: windows, lan, shared-folders

I have two PCs (let's say **PC1** and **PC2**) connected to each other through the LAN cable. From this connection, I created a share folder which can be accessed from both PCs. However, most of the time when there is a file inside the folder, **PC1** is able to detect the file while **PC2** detected that the folder is still empty. If I try to copy and paste the file with the same exact name from **PC2** into the folder, Windows will prompt out warning message whether to replace the current file inside the folder. If I click "No" and refresh the folder, then only the file will re-appear.

Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the folder on PC2? Pressing F5 within Windows Explorer should do the trick.

Comment: @johm01dav I did. The file still wont appear until u somehow trigger it